# How do I handle encoding for importing foreign movie titles with diacritics into a database?

Tags: bash, encoding, utf-8, psql, diacritics

There may not be one rule to this, but I am trying to find a way to deal with encoding between a PSQL import and retrieving and displaying records in bash or other programs. I am really new to the idea of encoding, so please bear with me! I'm running into issues with the character 'é'. I've gotten the error `ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe9 0x72 0x61` on import (I believe the default on it is UTF-8) and was able to temporarily fix it by changing the encoding to Windows-1251 on the import. However, trying to retrieve the data in bash gave me the error `ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xd0 0xb9 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"`, so I assumed bash was using 1252 encoding.

I deleted it all and re-imported with WIN1252 encoding, and it worked for both import and retrieval. My concern is whether I may run into issues down the line with displaying this character or trying to retrieve it on a browser. Currently, if I select the movie by id in bash, I get `Les MisΘrables`. Honestly, not ideal, but it's okay with me if there won't be errors. It did scare me, though, when the query couldn't be completed because of an encoding mismatch.

From my little understanding of UTF-8, I feel like the character 'é' should have been accepted in the first place. I searched online for a character set and that was on it. Can anyone tell me a little more about any of this? My inclination is to go with UTF-8 as it seems the most ubiquitous, but I don't know why it was giving me trouble. Thanks!

EDIT: My complete lack of knowledge surrounding encoding led me to never save the file specifically encoded as UTF-8. That solved it. Thanks to all who looked into this!

Comment: Everything needs to understand UTF-8.  For `cmd`, see `chcp 65001`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Described three different individual problems in the question. Code examples given in Python (commonly comprehensible, I hope).

**1st** *`ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe9 0x72 0x61`* means exactly what said: it's not *UTF-8*:

```
>>> print(bytearray([0xe9,0x72,0x61]).decode('latin1'))
éra
```

**2nd** *`ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xd0 0xb9 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"`*. Source is UTF-8, result is Cyrillic (`'WIN1251'`):

```
>>> print(bytearray([0xd0,0xb9]).decode('UTF-8'))
й
```

**3rd**  *I get `Les MisΘrables`* (probably instead of `Les Misérables`?) It's a flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case:

```
>>> print('Les Misérables'.encode('latin1').decode('cp437'))
Les MisΘrables
```

In fine, here's a recapitulation of discussed byte values and corresponding characters. Note that the column '`CodePoint`' contains Unicode (`U+hhhh`) and UTF-8 bytes:

```
Char CodePoint                  Category Description
---- ---------                  -------- -----------
   é {U+00E9, 0xC3,0xA9} LowercaseLetter Latin Small Letter E With Acute
   r {U+0072, 0x72}      LowercaseLetter Latin Small Letter R
   a {U+0061, 0x61}      LowercaseLetter Latin Small Letter A
   Ð {U+00D0, 0xC3,0x90} UppercaseLetter Latin Capital Letter Eth
   ¹ {U+00B9, 0xC2,0xB9}     OtherNumber Superscript One
   й {U+0439, 0xD0,0xB9} LowercaseLetter Cyrillic Small Letter Short I
   Θ {U+0398, 0xCE,0x98} UppercaseLetter Greek Capital Letter Theta
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The mojibake thing makes sense, and I expected it to come out in a weird way because they were encoded differently. I guess what I'm confused about is how the é ends up encoded to not be UTF-8. I tried inputting the specific character it into the text file via a few methods (and used notepad, which I think defaults to UTF-8). I can only assume at some point in the chain the encoding was changed? Swamped today, but upvoted for now and will see if I can get something to work with the table you gave as soon as I can. Thanks again!

Comment: I looked into this and realized I made a pretty stupid mistake of not specifying coding in the saved file. I believe it was encoded as ASCII, and I just didn't know enough to know I could save with a specific encoding from notepad. This all has helped me learn a lot about encoding, though, so thank you!